# node.js bracket syntax

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to understand some code used to make a Node.js dispatcher but I can't understand one line. Maybe my JavaScript gap . . . I commented the code with my doubts.

```
var HttpDispatcher = function() {
  this.listeners = { get: [ ], post: [ ] };
}

HttpDispatcher.prototype.on = function(method, url, cb) {
  this.listeners[method].push({
    cb: cb,
    url: url
  });
}

HttpDispatcher.prototype.onGet = function(url, cb) {
  this.on('get', url, cb);
}

HttpDispatcher.prototype.onPost = function(url, cb) {
  this.on('post', url, cb);
}

HttpDispatcher.prototype.dispatch = function(req, res) {
  var parsedUrl = require('url').parse(req.url, true);
  var method = req.method.toLowerCase();
  this.listener[method][parsedUrl.pathname](req, res); // i don't understand this line
}
```

Why do we refer to `this.listener` as a bidimensional array? We defined listeners like an array of object! and why do we pass parameters?

Answer (score 1):

It's not a bidimensional array, its [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors) being used to access a nested property of an object.

```
this.listener[method][parsedUrl.pathname](req, res)
|-------------------||------------------||--------|
 ^object property of  ^nested function    ^ invocation of the function 
  the listener object  of the listener
  where the property   object where the
  key is the method    property key is
                       the path name
```

Properties of nested objects can be accessed by chaining dot and/or bracket references together. The following are all equivalent:

```
object.baz.foo.bar;
object["baz"]["foo"]["bar"];
object["baz"].foo["bar"];
```

Check [this](http://www.sitepoint.com/back-to-basics-javascript-object-syntax/) for more details.

Comment: I can understand that with this.listeners['get'] we can access get array but in get array we have two properties

Comment: yes that's right, properties of nested objects can be accessed by chaining brackets together - if that's what you mean?

Comment: So here this.listener[method][parsedUrl.pathname](req, res); we access only to one property?

Comment: i've updated my explanation to make it clearer - it only accesses one function, so it can call it, but it uses 2 bracket references to reach it because its nested within the listener object

Comment: are we accessing to "cb" property or "url" property, inside listeners object?